# How to create a two-dimensional numpy array from two tif files in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, google-colaboratory, tiff

I am working in Google Colab.
I have imported two tif files with 1000 rows and 1000 columns with the following script:

```
import cv2

green = cv2.imread('green.tif')
nir = cv2.imread('nir.tif')
```

I want to create an array which will have a two-dimensional vector in every pixel with the value of the green.tif in the first dimension and the value of the nir.tif in the second dimension.

How can i do this?

Comment: Do you mean first row and second row instead of dimension?

Comment: I want to create an array. Every pixel of this array will have a two dimensional vector with the value of the green.tif in the first dimension and the value of the nir.tif in the second dimension.

Comment: So @Ehsan's answer is good but in light of this last message I think you should replace `np.vstack((green,nir))` by `np.stack((green, nir), axis=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you  want to interlace the two volumes and consider *green* as channel 1 and *nir* as channel 2 you can proceed as follows:

```
ch1 = np.ones((2,2,2))
ch2 = np.zeros((2,2,2))

out = np.empty((4,2,2))

out[::2,:,:] = ch1
out[1::2,:,:] = ch2

out = out.reshape((2,2,2,2))
```

Output:

```
>>> print(out)
[[[[1. 1.]
   [1. 1.]]

  [[0. 0.]
   [0. 0.]]]


 [[[1. 1.]
   [1. 1.]]

  [[0. 0.]
   [0. 0.]]]]
```

If you only want to do "first row - second row", just look at `np.stack`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably simply want:

```
np.vstack((green,nir))
```

example:

```
green = np.array([1, 2, 3])
nir = np.array([2, 3, 4])
```

output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

And if you want to stack the horizontally, use `np.hstack`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of two 2D images you can proceed as follows:
Each element `out[i, j]` will be a vector so the first element will be `green[i, j]` and the second `nir[i, j]`.

```
green = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
nir = np.array([[3, 2], [1, 0]])*-1

out = np.stack((green, nir), axis=2)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(out[0,0])
[ 0 -3]
```